# Will "collection.Remove(Query<T>.Where(predicate))" will try to delete as much as possible even if error is encountered?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, removeall

What I really want to know is if the following operation will try to remove all documents even if one of these cannot be removed for any reason:

Using MongoDB C# driver:

```
collection.Remove(Query<T>.Where(predicate));
```

I want to know this because I'm performing rollback operation and I want to remove all documents matching the query even if a document for some reason cannot be deleted.

Remove as much as possible...

Will this operation throw an exception if a document cannot be removed or will continue till the end and return an error at the end?

Thank you.

What I used at first:

```
        bool success = true;

        #region Delete everything

        try
        {
            foreach (Person person in persons)
            {
                try
                {
                    PersonRepository.Delete(person );
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        #endregion
```

But I want to replace the above code with:

```
PersonRepository.Delete(Query<Person>.Where(p => p.Name == name));
```

Under Delete method of PersonRepository I use now:

```
collection.Remove(Query<T>.Where(predicate));
```

Will this try to remove all persons even if any of them cannot be removed for any magical reason?

Comment: Are you sure? MongoDB does not provide ACID in collection multi document writes. Only single document write ACID is supported.